# Capture entire tableview cell range in snapshot for printing and sharing

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, spreadsheet

I'm trying to snapshot an entire scrollview, the "scrollview" is a tableview which is a SpreadsheetView pod. The SpreadsheetView is actually a scrollview/tableview. The way I've set it up is to dequereusablecell. Really I don't know any other way as I'm new to all this. Problem is this causes the image to render on only part of the saved snapshotted image.

How can I capture the entire spreadsheetview/tableview?

I have searched and searched but there isn't any conclusive way I've found to do this that I can understand or tweak...

Share function:

```
// Share function for share button
@objc func shareTapped() {
    
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(spreadsheetView.contentSize)

    let savedContentOffset = spreadsheetView.contentOffset
    let savedFrame = spreadsheetView.frame

    spreadsheetView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
    spreadsheetView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: spreadsheetView.contentSize.width, height: spreadsheetView.contentSize.height)

    spreadsheetView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    spreadsheetView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
    spreadsheetView.frame = savedFrame

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    // Give sharing functionality
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image!], applicationActivities: [])
    vc.excludedActivityTypes = [.assignToContact, .addToReadingList]
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    present(vc, animated: true)
    
}
```

Spreadsheetview setup:

```
// First initialize column and row headers & add grid data
func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Cell? {
    let cell = spreadsheetView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellStyle.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellStyle
    cell.printable(with: "0")
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    if case 0 = indexPath.row {
        cell.printable(with: columnHeaders[indexPath.section])
        return cell
    } else if case 0 = indexPath.section {
        cell.printable(with: rowHeaders[indexPath.row])
        return cell
// Spreadsheet setup
func numberOfColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    columnHeaders.count }
func numberOfRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    rowHeaders.count }
func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, widthForColumn column: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if case 0 = column {
        return 90
    } else {
        return 60
    }
}
func spreadsheetView(_ spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView, heightForRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    18  }
func frozenColumns(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    1   }
func frozenRows(in spreadsheetView: SpreadsheetView) -> Int {
    1   }
```

EDIT: This also does not work:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(spreadsheetView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

    for section in 0..<spreadsheetView.numberOfColumns {
        for row in 0..<spreadsheetView.numberOfRows {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            guard let cell = spreadsheetView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { continue }
            cell.contentView.drawHierarchy(in: cell.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableView` only renders the visible cells you could try creating a new table view that has the same frame as its content so that all cells are visible but I'm not sure how much of a performance hit that would be. Also you could build your own "spreadsheet" in a `UIView` and snapshot that.

Comment: I think that is above my level of knowledge :(